after upgrading our visual studio projects to 2022, It gives errors with DirectX. qedit not found
after upgrading our visual studio projects to 2022, It gives errors with DirectX.
IT seems we may have to use windows SDK instead of DirectX in the latest VS projects. I tried to copy the missing headers like qedit.h. and tried to copy missing headers. But still I ednded up with the below errors.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\d3drmobj.h(454,42): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'LPDIRECT3DVIEWPORT'
1>(compiling source file 'StdAfx.cpp')
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\d3drmobj.h(500,42): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'LPDIRECT3DVIEWPORT'
1>(compiling source file 'StdAfx.cpp')
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\d3drm.h(74,15): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'LPDIRECT3D'
1>(compiling source file 'StdAfx.cpp')
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\d3drm.h(156,15): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'LPDIRECT3D2'
1>(compiling source file 'StdAfx.cpp')
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\d3drm.h(240,15): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'LPDIRECT3D2'


Please provide more information and also format your code/error message for clarity.

Hi, this tool is to convert our proprietary file format to mp4 or other standard video formats. we are currently using vs2010 and compile this utility with DirectX 9.0 SDK . It was compiling file. But after migrating our poject to vs 2020, it starts giving error "should not include d3dtypes.h when compiling for DX8 or newer interfaces" .  Here iare the include we use :
#include <olectl.h>
// DirectX SDK Required!
#include <dshow.h>
#include <dshowasf.h>
#include <qedit.h>
#include <mediaobj.h>
// Windows Media Format SDK required

This smells like DirectDraw (DirectX 8?) wich is pre DirectX9 (more like 25 years ago). You might have the old DirectX8 SDK files, or you can get it from here https://github.com/edgeforce/directx8 but you may face other issues after that.

Which version of Visual Studio did you upgrade from?

Upgrading from visual studio 2010 to 2022.
